# Tour of a private beta site shouldn't say it requires 50 rep to comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta, tour

The tour of a private beta site it shouldn't say it requires 50 rep to comment. The following picture explains the place where I'm talking about:

[image]

Please note that this section is not in the Meta Stack Exchange tour.

To clarify: Its only in this section. The other section says correctly that it only requires 1 reputation.

Comment: Please link the tour page so we can see it or at least link a photo of the entire section of the tour that has that part.

Comment: @PythonMaster http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/tour under "Improve posts by editing or commenting". Looks like that this part is fixed and not per-site configurable like the reputation requirements in Tim's answer.

Comment: It does not actually  say that 50 rep are required. The statement amounts to "have 50 rep => can comment everywhere", which is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in build 2860.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't for me:

[image]

Are we talking about a different place to [this tour](/tour)?

Edit - It shows this image in one place, but see the image in OP - in another place it says 50.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated the question with an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currently in a private beta, but I can see that you somehow are seeing the information for a ***public beta site***, which is kinda awkward. This is a definite bug but I can't find the exact section where you see this though. Unless you're confused between public and private beta, this needs to be fixed fast. Screenshot of public beta tour for Coffee.SE:

[image]

Comment: See the updated question with a screenshot.